# How to using write() system call write an integer in to file

Tags: c, filesystems, buffer, system-calls

How can i write the integer in to the file by using the write() system call

```
 //write(fd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
 //The buffer in the write() system call has to be an char[]; 
 //if i want to write integer such as 

for(int i = 0, i < 10; i++){

    write(fd,i.??); // error 
    // How can i write the integer in to the file by using the write() system call
}
```

Comment: `write(fd, &i, sizeof i);`

Comment: This will write the binary value as befits the use of `write`. If you want the textual representation then use `fprintf`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want binary output:

```
 write(fd, &i, sizeof(i));
```

If you want text output, one decimal number per line:

```
char tmpbuf[50];
int n = sprintf(tmpbuf, "%d\n", i);
write(fd, tmpbuf, n);
```

If you want text output, 8 hexadecimal digits per int:

```
char tmpbuf[20];
int n = sprintf(tmpbuf, "%08X", i);
write(fd, tmpbuf, n);
```

If you're not sure which you want, try it all three ways, and take a look at the resulting output files.  (The "binary" output won't be easily visible without a "hex dump" program, or binary editor.)

Answer (score -2):

you can use `sprintf()` function to create the string first, and then use it in `write()` such as:

```
char number_s[2];
sprintf(number_s,"%2d",i);
write(fd,number_s,strlen(number_s));
```

Comment: Sadly that will overflow `number_s`. Don't forget the string terminator, or that `%2d` does not guarantee that only 2 digits are written.

Comment: @WeatherVane `%2s` doesn't limit the output to two characters anyway.

Comment: @thangpx1706 It's not clear the OP wants a string.  (Maybe, maybe not).  Also, `[2]` is *waayy* too small.

Comment: @Steve This is just an example because in his problem the `i` variable is only in a range of `0` to `10`, and I think 2 is enough.

Comment: `char number_s[2];` and plain `%d` would work for single-digit numbers.  `%2d` guarantees overflow for any numbers.  The OP's example was just an example; a robust solution would work without complaint for larger inputs.  Sizing arrays like `number_s` to be just barely as big as one thinks they need to be is false, pointless economy.